# TFS Branch Parent

Tags: tfs

Is it possible in TFS 2008 to alter the parent of a branch?  I've heard this will be available in 2010, but was wondering if there was an equivelent in 2008 (even if it's more long winded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a baseless merge from the command line then you'll be able to merge again in the future from the command line without it being baseless.

http://benoit808.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/baseless-merge-with-tfs/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx